# Different DbContexts for different user roles

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture

So. Сan you explain to me whether the correct approach would be to have different DBContext for different types of users.

For example:
We have ApiController with 2 methods:

```
[HttpGet, Route("admin"), Authorize(RoleType.Admin)]
public Task<...> Get(... adminRequest)
{
    var query = mapper<AdminGetCommand>(adminRequest);
    return mediatr.Send(query);
}

[HttpGet, Route(""), Authorize(RoleType.User)]
public Task<...> Get(... userRequest)
{
    var query = mapper<UserGetCommand>(userRequest);
    return mediatr.Send(query);
}
```

after that every command depends on different Service/DbContext witch has different configuration.
For example:

```
//filter for users
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.ApplyGlobalFilters<IDeletedUtcDateTime>(e => !e.DeletedUtcDateTime.HasValue);

}
...

//filter for admin 
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    ...
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    ...
}
...
```

I feel like I'm missing something or better solution exists here

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Please read more carefully, everything in post. No problem, just a question already answered by David Browne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сan you explain to me whether the correct approach would be to have different DBContext for different types of users.

It's a reasonable approach if you want a different set of global query filters (or other mapping or behavior changes) for the users.  You can simply derive UserDbContext from AdminDbContext or derive both from a base DbContext, and register them separately in DI.